# Java 8 - Convert to java.util.Map from Stream Object

Tags: java, java-8

The `workspace` and `project` instance objects are associated with `Rally` object which hold in `List` object.

```
class Rally {
    Workspace workspace;

    public Workspace getWorkspace() {
        return workspace;
    }

    public void setWorkspace(Workspace workspace) {
        this.workspace = workspace;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    Project project;

    Rally(String name, Workspace workspace, Project project) {
        this.workspace = workspace;
        this.project = project;

    }
}

class Workspace {

    public Workspace(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Project {
    private String id;

    public Project(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

How to get `workspace` `id` and `project` `id` to another `HashMap`?

```
rallyInList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(r->r.getWorkspace().getId(),b->b.getProject().getId()));
```

[image]

Comment: Please 1) Format your code, this is somewhat illegible and 2) post the full error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Your stream pipeline is basically correct.

You just need to assign the result to a `Map`. Assuming `getId()` methods return a `String`:

```
Map<String,String> map =
  rallyInList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(r->r.getWorkspace().getId(),
                                       r->r.getProject().getId(),
                                       (v1,v2)->v2));
```

Also make sure all the methods you are using actually exist (for example, it should be `getId()`, not `getID()`).

EDIT:

> it is causing the issue while runtime. illegal state exception. Normally if we add duplicate key in hashmap, it will allow and update value alone.

The variant of `Collectors.toMap` you are using doesn't allow duplicate keys. You have to use the variant that requires a merge function.

Comment: I tried the same. But problem is eclipse is not giving auto populate the method , ie . r.getWorkpace() is not coming under suggestion.  and another one is Map<String,String> map is causing because of result would be Map<Object,Object>. any idea. I know it is returning String,String

Comment: @LearnHadoop The `Rally` class you posted is missing the `getWorkspace()` and `getProject()` methods, which you should add. The error messages are sometimes misleading. For example, I got the `Map<Object,Object>` error message when I used `getID()` (as you did in the question) instead of the correct method name, which is `getId()`.

Comment: Just i have posted partial code. Complete code below. `class Rally {
 Workspace workspace;

 public Workspace getWorkspace() {
  return workspace;
 }

 public void setWorkspace(Workspace workspace) {
  this.workspace = workspace;
 }

 public Project getProject() {
  return project;
 }

 public void setProject(Project project) {
  this.project = project;
 }

 Project project;

 Rally(String name, Workspace workspace, Project project) {
  this.workspace = workspace;
  this.project = project;

 }
}`

Comment: @LearnHadoop you should post that in the question (you can edit your question). And I added the missing getter methods and the code passed compilation for me.

Comment: Edit and updated my code. Hope it wil  give some idea.

Comment: @LearnHadoop you still have to change `getID()` to `getId()` in your stream pipeline. that was the only issue with the code you posted.

Comment: Updated the code.. Not sure.. why i can't convert into map. Seems pipeline code is fine and without any compilation issue. if i assign the result to Map<String,String> ,then  it is throwing compile time error

Comment: @LearnHadoop your updated code passes compilation for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: Pasted issue in picture? can you please check?.. Eclipse is not providing getWorkspace() method

Comment: @LearnHadoop So your problem is that auto-completion doesn't work? What if you type getWorkspace()? Do you get any error?

Comment: S. Also if add this line Map<String, String> re = rallyInList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getWorkspace().getId(), b -> b.getProject().getId())); System.out.println(re); it is causing the issue while runtime. illegal state exception. Normally if we add duplicate key in hashmap, it will allow and update value alone. Am i correct? But i lamda it is throwing error

Comment: @LearnHadoop So the issue is duplicate keys. You should have mentioned that before. You should add a merge function that resolves duplicates. See edit.

Comment: Duplicate issue also after dot it is not listing all methods in that instance.